# Cycles: make a bouncing ball with physical simulation

Tags: animation, physics

I want to make an animation of some ball which have horizontal initial velocity bouncing on floor. I tried to add Rigid to the ball (dynamic) and floor (static). But the ball dropped to the floor without a bounce. I googled for answer but what they do are move the ball to approximate position and set a key frame, don't care much about physical rules. I do believe blender can deal with such a easy simulation.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You must set the ball to rigid body, and increase the bounciness value for both the ball and the floor.

Comment: @Anthony Forwood Exactly where might I find this "bounciness" value???

Comment: @InternetWarriors Properties -> Physics -> Rigid Body Collisions -> Surface Response -> Bounciness